# How to set route by mac address on Windows?

Tags: windows, batch, routing, mac-address, network-interface

This is the way how many of us do set a route on windows:

*route add 10.10.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0 10.77.77.1 if **58** -p*

In the command line ***58*** is the Interface Index (IF) and most of the time its value is constant for a specific network interface card. Therefore one can create a CMD batch file to automate deletion and re-setting of all the routes she/he need.

However, in my case I have a USB 3.0 to Dual Port Gigabit Ethernet Adapter NIC, and its IFs change every time when I connect to the USB port of my notebook. What I do, just open a *cmd* shell, get the current Interface IDs by giving *route print*, then open the CMD batch file with text editor and change all the old IF (ex: ***58***) values, save&close, and at last run the CMD batch file on the shell.

If there is a way to set a route only by knowing the MAC address, not depending of the IF - then the problem is solved :) The solution may be a simple one line CMD command (*set route by MAC*), or maybe first get the IF by MAC and set route by IF (*set route by IF of the MAC*).

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next code snippet shows how-to *get the IF by MAC* using [`FOR /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) against result of [WMIC (Windows Management Instrumentation Command)](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "_maca=AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA"            change to match your circumstances
set "_geta=InterfaceIndex^, MACAddress"    to keep next lines in reasonable length
set "_ifin="                               to ensure that `_ifin` variable is empty

for /F "tokens=1,*" %%G in ('
    WMIC NIC where "MACAddress='%_maca%'" get %_geta% 2^>NUL ^| find ":"
                            ') do set "_ifin=%%~G"

if defined _ifin (
        rem route command block here:
    route add 10.10.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0 10.77.77.1 if %_ifin% -p
) else (
    echo %_maca%: No Instance^(s^) Available.
)
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`2>NUL` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)
- (`"Double Quotes"`, `^` Caret etc.) [Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

Comment: Thank you very much @JosefZ, this is the solution to my problem!